# Ender 3 S1 Pro Probe Failed when auto-levelling even after manual level

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, z-probe, automatic-bed-leveling

When I first bought the Ender 3 S1 Pro, everything worked fine, but at some point, the auto-leveling stopped working. I used to manually level it every dozen or so prints (sheet of paper method) just to make sure things were close, then auto-level before each print. Now, I can manually level it, but once it is manually leveled. If I tell it to auto-level, it will fail with a "203 probe failed", usually on the first probe point. I've actually almost given up on the auto-leveling and I have removed the `G29` from the initial G-code.

I will admit, I have once or twice manually leveled it and tried to then auto-level, just to see if it would work, and gotten to complete an auto-level, but if I then put `G29` in the next G-code I want to print, it will fail with the same "probe failed".

Any clue what may have happened here? Before I buy another CR Touch sensor and replace it just to have another one fail. Is there something I can "reset"?

Comment: Have you checked the cable?